# How to set more than one alarms at a time in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am making a small app where I have to set alarm from array but only one alarm is set and working at a time which is at last position of array why it is behaving like this following is my code

```
AlarmManager[] alarmManager=new AlarmManager[24];
                for(f=0;f<arr2.length;f++)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmR.this, Riciving.class);
                    pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmR.this, 0,intent, 0);

                    alarmManager[f] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager[f].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,arr2[f] ,pi);

                    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can use this [More than one alarms](http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=3503)

Comment: @Uttam Utils.getTimeAfterInSecs(45);is not working because there is no internal class Utils so how I can achieve the same

Comment: Hello can you please post full code with receiver Multiple alarm at same time ..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On your `pendingIntent` you need to set the second `requestCode` to a unique number. I usually run the array through a for loop and set the request code dynamically for each item in the array. Without the `requestCode` the alarms are overwriting each other.

```
AlarmManager[] alarmManager=new AlarmManager[24];
intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
for(f=0;f<arr2.length;f++){
   Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmR.this, Riciving.class);
   pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmR.this, f,intent, 0);

   alarmManager[f] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager[f].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,arr2[f] ,pi);

   intentArray.add(pi);

}
```

Basically, you just want to change `requestCode` to a dynamic number. By setting it to `f` you are giving it a new unique id for every item in the array. Keep in mind, if you want to cancel the alarms you will need to use another for loop and cancel each one individually. I personally add all my alarms to their own array so I can handle them separately.

Then if you need to cancel them:

```
    private void cancelAlarms(){
    if(intentArray.size()>0){
        for(int i=0; i<intentArray.size(); i++){
            alarmmanager.cancel(intentArray.get(i));
        }
        intentArray.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with some code. Keep in mind, this does not go along with the documentation. I had to deal with this not to long ago on a project I am working on.

Comment: Why the array of AlarmManager-s ?

Comment: While relaunching the app, the array values are resettled. Unable to remove the alarm. using the static values also the values are resettled. Unable to achieve to cancel the alarms in this way of unique id generation. Could you please help me to cancel all the alarms?

Comment: Hey Buddy.. You have saved my life .. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't understand what array is `arr2`! Could someone help?

Comment: What if Alarm no 1 was set then app was closed, then before alarm ringing, app is opened and another alarm i set. Wouldn't it overwrite the previous one, as the array index for the loop would be 0 for both alarms, so the request code would be same?