# Only Second Alarm is executing why?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have two AlarmManager in my activity as follows,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private AlarmManager alarm1,alarm2;  
    private Intent intent1,intent2; 
    private PendingIntent pi1,pi2;

    private int HOUR=15,MINUTE=46,SECOND=10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR );
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTE );
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, SECOND );

        intent1 = new Intent ( MainActivity.this, BroadCastAlarm.class );
        pi1 = PendingIntent.getService( MainActivity.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
        alarm1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
        alarm1.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi1 );

        Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR );
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTE );
        calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, SECOND+30 );

        intent2 = new Intent ( MainActivity.this, BroadCastAlarm.class );
        pi2 = PendingIntent.getService( MainActivity.this, 1, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
        alarm2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
        alarm2.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pi2 );
    }
}
```

BroadCastAlarm.java is only a service that display Toast message. Here whenever I am executing above code only second Alarm is getting execute. How come first Alarm is not getting executed ?

Comment: is it your problem solved or not?

Comment: @KarthickM Yes, The problem is solved and my application is working excellent since last 50 days

Comment: i am also working with that one;i am using multiple alaram with lots of variation,But while selecting the second alaram the first alaram is overriding with the new one.

Comment: Then you should post a question with your code, like I did.

Comment: ,ok i will try your code now,i have one doubt in that one,what is the alarmreceiver class,why you are using that one,or this one <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="timer:" />
    </intent-filter> we need to add in service class or Mainactivity in the manifest file?

Comment: Instead of service, I am using BroadcastReceiver for Alarm. That's it

Comment: i tried your way,but not worked,can you look my code http://pastie.org/8539144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers suggest, the second alarm is overriding the first one as they share the same action. If you want to diferentiate alarms, and not just overriding your previous ones you must set an action.

first of all, you need to add this in your application's manifest tag:

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourcompany.yourpackage.AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="timer:" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When defining your intents, just add something like:

```
intent1.setData(Uri.parse("timer:intent1"));
...
intent2.setData(Uri.parse("timer:intent2"));
```

Then you just need to define a BroadcastReceiver class to do stuff. If you want a toast:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "I'm an alarm toast!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

I also suggest you to change your pending intent flags to: `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

Comment: BroadCastAlarm.java is only a service that display Toast message , I tried PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT but result is same.

Comment: change the service to a BroadcastReceiver if you can. as simple as the code provided

Comment: Ok, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: In case of Cancel an Alarm, do i need to cancel two times or just once is enough ?

Comment: You need to cancel each identificator.

Comment: @AlexCabrera for me the same problem is there,i am using multiple alaram with lots of variation,But while selecting the second alaram the first alaram is overriding with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The `PendingIntents` represent the same `Intent`, hence your alarms are identical, hence your second alarm replaces the first one.

From the documentation,

> If you use two `Intent` objects that are equivalent as per `Intent.filterEquals`, then you will get the same `PendingIntent` for both of them.

Also,

> `requestCode`  Private request code for the sender (currently not used).

(that the value you changed from 0 to 1)

Comment: I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12791212/2567598) answer already, I tried changing PendingIntent's value as 0 & 1 but still only one alarm is getting executed.

Comment: Please refer my question once again.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation once (again).

Comment: can you give me the doc link please ?

Answer (score 0):

intent of alarm1 is replaced by the intent of alarm2. This is basic reason why only second alarm is working.

Comment: Please refer my question once again.