# trigger an alarm on particular date and particular time

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I have a `AlarmManager` that triggers different `notifications` on various days. It displays the `notification` of past dates but doesn't show the `notifications` for future date time.
I tried putting hard coded string then it works fine, but when i get the dates from server then the alarm manager doesn't fire. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. 
Here is My Code:

**ReminderAlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class ReminderAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String REMINDER = "reminder";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, REMINDER);
    // Acquire the lock
    wakeLock.acquire();

    Intent service = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    service.putExtra("id", intent.getStringExtra("id"));
    service.putExtra("subject", intent.getStringExtra("subject"));
    service.putExtra("description", intent.getStringExtra("description"));
    context.startService(service);

    // Release the lock
    wakeLock.release();
}

public void setReminder(Context context, List<PlannerData> planner) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(AttributeSet.Constants.DATE_FORMAT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (PlannerData data : planner) {
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse(data.getReminderDate().trim());
            calendar.setTime(d);
            long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();     // Notification Time
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmReceiver.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(planner.indexOf(data)));
                intent.putExtra("subject", data.getSubject());
                intent.putExtra("description", data.getDescription());
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pendingIntent);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}

}
```

**ReminderService.java**

```
public class ReminderService extends IntentService {

private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;

public ReminderService() {
    super("ReminderService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yellow)
    .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("subject") != null ? intent.getStringExtra("subject") : "")
    .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("description") != null ? intent.getStringExtra("description") : "");

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, PlannerActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the started Activity
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of your application to the Home Screen
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(PlannerActivity.class);

    resultIntent.setAction(intent.getStringExtra("id"));

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    long timeInMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.when = timeInMilis;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("id")), notification);

}
}
```

And my date format is :

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mistake.
For setting multiple alarms I need to create my PendingIntent s with different requestCode.
Below is my updated source code:

ReminderAlarmReceiver.java

```
public class ReminderAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String REMINDER = "reminder";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, REMINDER);
    // Acquire the lock
    wakeLock.acquire();

    Intent service = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    service.putExtra("id", intent.getStringExtra("id"));
    service.putExtra("subject", intent.getStringExtra("subject"));
    service.putExtra("description", intent.getStringExtra("description"));
    context.startService(service);

    // Release the lock
    wakeLock.release();
}

public void setReminder(Context context, List<PlannerData> planner) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(AttributeSet.Constants.DATE_FORMAT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (PlannerData data : planner) {
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse(data.getReminderDate().trim());
            calendar.setTime(d);
            long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();     // Notification Time
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(planner.indexOf(data)));
            intent.putExtra("subject", data.getSubject());
            intent.putExtra("description", data.getDescription());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, planner.indexOf(data), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pendingIntent);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

Got the solution from here: [Android Set Multiple Alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785702/android-set-multiple-alarms)!