# Android list view looping

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have customized listview of events with their dates. If the use selects a specific item on the list then my program will ask if the user want to be reminded of that event. I am having problem looping the events. For example, for position 1,if I set the reminder to be at 2:15pm and for position 2, I set reminder to be at 2:30. The notification of second list will appear ignoring the first one. I want both of these notifications to show at their respective time.

Can someone find out and help me on how to loop the list so I am able to set reminders on any item on the list.

Please check the OnClickResponse() method, that's where I am creating an alarm.

```
'public class Product extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private List<list> myList = new ArrayList<list>();
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
```

`private void fill_ListView() { 

                 ArrayAdapter<list> listArrayAdapter = new myListAdapter(); 

                 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.product_View); 

                 list.setAdapter(listArrayAdapter);
                                      }
            private void clickResponse() { 

                 ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.product_View); 

                 if(l!=null){ 

                     l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {                                          @Override 

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View viewClicked,                                                     final int position, long id) {                           

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(                                         Product.this); 

        alert.setTitle("Reminder!!"); 

        alert.setMessage("Do you want to be reminded of the expiry date of this product?”); 

        alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {              

@Override 

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                                              Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            // checking if first item is clicked then a reminder will be set for some date 

 if(position==0){                                             calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6); 

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);                                                          calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 04);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 38);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);                                             Intent myIntent = new Intent(Product.this, MyReceiver.class);                                             pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Product.this, 0,myIntent,0);                                                          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);                                             alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);                                                      }
        if(position==1){ 

         calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);                                                          calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 04);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 39);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);                                             calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);                                             Intent myIntent = new Intent(Product.this, MyReceiver.class);                                             pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Product.this, 0,myIntent,0);                                                          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);                                             alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);                                                      }                                             dialog.dismiss();                                     }              

        });              

        alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                                     @Override 

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                                      dialog.dismiss(); 

        } 

        });              

    alert.show();              

    } 

    }); 

        } 

      } 

            

    private class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<list> { 

    public myListAdapter() { 

    // what objects are going in there and how are they going to look                         super(Product.this, R.layout.custom_layout, myList); 

     }              

     @Override 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

           

     View itemView = convertView; 

                     if (itemView == null) { 

    itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);                         }                         list current_list = myList.get(position);                                                   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_image);                         imageView.setImageResource(current_list.getIconId());              

    // getting the title of the event 

    TextView titleTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_event);                         titleTxt.setText(current_list.getName());                                                   // getting the description             //

    TextView desp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_desp);             //            desp.setText(current_list.getDetails()); 

     EditText text = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_desp);                         text.setText(current_list.getDetails());                                                   TextView date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_date);                         date.setText(current_list.getDate());              

     return itemView; 

}                           

 }`
enter code here'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Product.this, 0,myIntent,0);
```

The second parameter stands for requestCode and it has to be unique for different alarms. You are setting it to 0 every time because of which the previous alarm gets overridden.

Comment: I changed second parameter of the second if statement to 1 but now the first works fine but second alarm doesn't even show

Comment: could you please explain more on this. thanks. The first appear and second one appears but not separately. When second alarm is called, the first one is still overrideen

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252623/how-to-set-more-than-one-alarms-at-a-time-in-android). It is exactly what you're looking for.